# mutiple curve fitting in binary images

Tags: python

I have a binary image which contains 0s and 1s only. There are few trend lines in the image as shown below, is there any way to extract those lines from the image?

[image: Example image showing diagonal lines]

Comment: If they always go on about the same angle then you can simply have a check in the code to look toward the bottom right and if it's not going in that direction then it will look either side to get the best fit. (Make a var for xpos and ypos and add one to both to look to the bottom right, if it does not see any it can then look either side and forward using a similar technique.)

Comment: What do you mean extract? Get the equation(s) of the line(s)? Get the pixels on the line?

Comment: Are they all always parallel? Do you mean they always occur at the same angle and you want to know if they are present? Or do you mean they are always present and you want to know their angle? Or something else?

Comment: @0x263A I want to get the pixels only, fitting the curves seems difficult.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, they may not be parallel, they can be curved lines sometimes, although it is not obvious in my picture. These curves always present and I want to know how many lines are there and their corresponding pixels.

Comment: I think a couple of further example images might help. Also I don't see how your images consist of only zeroes and ones - there seem to be more than 2 colours.

Comment: Also, it would be simpler to test ideas out if you shared your actual images rather than plots of them with colormaps and axes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way to extract the lines would be to use a RANSAC
algorithm iteratively.

It identifies the points that are close to a model function and
then removes them from the image. This allows to extract
a separate line in the next iteration.

Use *y* = *a* *x* + *b* as model function (where *x* and
*y* are the image coordinates and *a* should come out as close to
−1).

An implementation would work roughly as follows:

1. Convert the image to a representation that allows you to treat
   it as a set *S* of points where the value is 1 (in the
   simplest case, a `list` or `set` of (*x*, *y*) tuples).
2. Pick one point (*x*<sub>0</sub>, *y*<sub>0</sub>) from *S*
   randomly and determine *b*<sub>0</sub> such that
   *y*<sub>0</sub> = −*x*<sub>0</sub> + *b*<sub>0</sub>
   (i.e., draw a line with slope
   *a*<sub>0</sub> = −1 through the chosen
   point).
3. Find all points (*x*, *y*) in *S* that are "close" to the
   line
   *y* = *a*<sub>0</sub> *x* + *b*<sub>0</sub>
   and add them to a new set *L*.

   (For example by using the condition
   |*a*<sub>0</sub> *x* + *b*<sub>0</sub> − *y*| < *t*
   for some threshold value *t*. Given that the lines in the
   image are vertically spaced by about 85, *t* = 20 might be
   a good choice.)
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 several times and remember the value for
   *b*<sub>0</sub> where *L* contained the most points.
5. Refine *a*<sub>0</sub> and *b*<sub>0</sub>, e.g. by doing
   a least-squares fit of the model function to all points in
   *L*, to obtain final values *a* and *b* (this step is
   optional, you could just use *a*<sub>0</sub> and
   *b*<sub>0</sub> directly). Now you have found one line.
6. Remove all points in *L* from *S*.
7. Repeat from step 2 as many times as needed to find all lines
   in the image.  At the end there are only "noise" points left
   in *S*.

Comment: Thank you for so detailed instruction, really appreciate it! Actually the "lines" appear in the image are not strictly "straight", is it possible to fit the pixels with the "curves"?

Comment: Yes, you could use a more complicated model function. But I don't think it will be necessary here.